# Print STDOUT in the middle of 2 Pipes in Solaris(bash)

Tags: bash, unix, solaris

http://www.webdesignerdepot.com/rss.htm

I have the same  issue. This command:

./somescript.sh > ../log/scriptlog.log

requires the output of a command go to std out. but inside the script

command | mailx -s "Subject" recipient@somedomain.tld

what I would like to do is something like :

command | tee > /dev/stdout | mailx -s "Subject" recipient@somedomain.tld

Where the output of the command goes to stdout( to be redirected into the ..log/scriptlog.log file )

and also into stdin for the mailx command.

Any way to do that?

Answer (score 1):

`tee` already sends to stdout.

```
... | tee -a log/scriptlog.log | ...
```

Answer (score 1):

```
exec 3>&1
command | tee /dev/fd/3 | mailx ...
```

or, using process substitution:

```
command | tee >(mailx ...)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'll try process substitution. To clarifily, I have a cron'd shell script . The cron entry is similar to:
/usr/script/myscript.sh > /usr/log/myscript.log

inside the script is a line similar to:
command | mailx -s "Subject" recipient

Since stdout from 'command' is being piped into the mailx command, it does appear in the log file 'myscript.log', but I want it to.

I tried capturing it into a variable but the line feeds appear to be lost that way. I could use a temporary file, but I was hoping for something more elegant.